# In ASP.NET Web API 2, how do I preserve object references across JSON serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, python-2.7, asp.net-web-api2

I have a REST API created using ASP.NET Web API 2 and Entity Framework 6. I want to serialize/deserialize objects and keep references to other objects.

I have defined a Tag model class in ASP.NET which also has a vanilla controller class generated by scaffolding:

```
// C#
// Tag.cs
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Tag Parent { get; set; } // I know this can't be circular 
}

...

// Context.cs
...
public DbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasOptional(_ => _.Parent);
```

I'm creating a client in Python with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [jsonPickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/) modules.  I have an equivalent class defined in Python:

```
# Python 
class Tag():
    def __init__(self, jSrc=None):
        #super(DBEntity,self).__init__()        
        self.ID = 0        
        self.Value = ""
        self.Parent = None

        if(jSrc != None):
             self.__dict__ = jsonpickle.decode(jSrc)
```

The following Python code works correctly to create a Tag entry in the Tags table:

```
newTag = Tag()
newTag.Value = "Parent"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post("http://server/api/Tags", data=jsonpickle.encode(newTag), headers=headers)


# ID | Value  | Parent_ID
# 1  | Parent | -
```

But when I assign a Parent Tag to a tag object with the correct ID set, 2x new Tag entries are created instead of the Parent ID reference being used:

```
# Get Tag
rg = requests.get("http://server/api/Tags/1")
parentTag = Tag(rg.text)

# Create new Tag with Parent reference
newTag = Tag()
newTag.Value = "Child"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post("http://server/api/Tags", data=jsonpickle.encode(newTag), headers=headers)

# ID | Value  | Parent_ID
# 1  | Parent | -
# 2  | Parent | - << This should net be created
# 3  | Child  | 2 << This should be 1
```

Database now contains 2x "Parent" Tags, however The "Child" Tag's Parent_ID field is correctly set to the new incorrectly created "Parent" Tag.

How Can I tell ASP.NET systems to lookup the Parent Tag's ID and keep the reference to the original Tag instead of just deserializing the Parent property into a new Tag entry?

Answer (score 0):

Every request to ASP.NET, should get a new DbContext.  That means that every time you need to update the database, you should retrieve the record you wish to update and then update it, before `SaveChanges`.

If you just deserialise an object and SaveChanges, it will (as you are seeing) create a new record in the database.

I recommend you implement a standard 3 tier mechanism, with view models in you API/Controller, DTO in your business layer, and entities (which you currently have) in the database layer.

The easy (but I would suggest wrong) fix, would be in your controller, to do something like:

```
public void MyAPI(ApiViewModel vm) 
{
 var entity = _dbContext.Find(tag.Id);
 entity.Value = vm.Value;
 _dbContext.SaveChanges();
 return Ok();
}
```